# "No such file or directory (2)" for libswiftSecurity.dylib on XCode 7

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to build a project that was running ok on XCode 6 but I get the error

> "/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator/libswiftSecurity.dylib"
>   failed: No such file or directory (2)

I checked the contents of both XCode 6 & 7 on disk and the file exists in the older version but not on XCode 7. Is this something that someone else has faced?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to copy the file to that folder:

> cp ~/old_path/libswiftSecurity.dylib
>   ~/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator

Maybe this is only a problem of yours. It should be solved.

Comment: yes, thank you, I did that, but is it normal that the file is missing? Has anyone else confronted  the same problem?

Comment: yes, it did,thank you. Have you used XCode 7? Is it missing the same file?

Comment: I used it. but I don't do swift. therefore I don't know if the problem exists

Comment: @abinop I had the same problem also. hasan83 solution worked for me too. Looks like they forgot a file in beta 5 maybe ?

Comment: I get an error when that mentions something about code signing.

It seems like this works for me when I compile for the simulator; however, not on a real device, I get a different error--even after copying.

Comment: what is your error? did you open a question for it? put link here

Comment: Apple forgot a lib? I don't think so, maybe apple force us to del the lib, it's should be a cocoapods bug in the new Xcode version they didn't fit in.

Comment: This is an odd error. I didn't mind manually doing it in the betas, but I just opened the app store version and got the same error. It makes me think that the error is somehow on my end or in my configuration.

Answer (score 26):

I ran into the same problem and was able to solve it by cleaning my `build folder`. In `Xcode Menu` do the following:

**`Product`** -> *(hold Alt key)* -> **`Clean Build Folder`**

After that step the error went away.

Comment: Working like a boss, Thanks

Comment: This fix also worked for an unrelated error where a build script was crashing after a bad return value from rsync