# upgraded to swift 2, and cocoapods -.38.2 now getting build error Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 23

Tags: xcode, swift2

How can I diagnose this error `Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 23`

```
sent 130971 bytes  received 42 bytes  262026.00 bytes/sec
total size is 130816  speedup is 1.00
rsync -auv "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator/libswiftSecurity.dylib" "/Users/jinteki/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-xyz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/Frameworks"
building file list ... rsync: link_stat "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator/libswiftSecurity.dylib" failed: No such file or directory (2)
done

sent 29 bytes  received 20 bytes  98.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-45/rsync/main.c(992) [sender=2.6.9]
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 23
```

Comment: looks like this is answered in this 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31914456/no-such-file-or-directory-2-for-libswiftsecurity-dylib-on-xcode-7-beta-5

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I had this same issues and I cleaned the Build Folder via:

Product -> hold ALT pressed -> Clean Build Folder

Comment: Thank you!! But why is this error showing up in the first place? Mine was saying:
xcode rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-45/rsync/main.c(992) [sender=2.6.9] Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 23

Comment: Looks like something is going wrong with rsync, usually the error 23 is thrown when there's no space left in the destination. Don't know why is happening here.

Thank you anyway, it worked for me too.

Answer (score 4):

Removing derived data works too
Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations -> tap on the derived data arrow -> Drag the derived data folder to trash

Answer (score 0):

I had the same and nothing helped. I deleted the Pods folder from my project and ran pod install again. It worked…