# Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 23

Tags: cocoapods, xcode7

I tried to update an app from Swift 1.2 to iOS 9.0, Xcode 7 and Swift 2.0 - but I have some problems with my pods when I try to compile the app.

I get the following error:

> sent 29 bytes  received 20 bytes  98.00 bytes/sec
>      total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
>      rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-45/rsync/main.c(992) [sender=2.6.9]
>      Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 23

Already checked for some solutions, but nothing worked for me:

Already tried:

- deleted all pods, and installed them again
- updated cocoapods (to a beta version) with sudo gem update cocoapods --pre
- removed cocoapods and installed again
- tried with "use_frameworks!" for all pods, and without

But still the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you see [this](https://support.ship.io/ios/rsync-error-23-during-embed-pods-frameworks-phase-for-cocoapods)?

Comment: Thanks! i will try that out

Comment: Does this answer your question? [upgraded to swift 2, and cocoapods -.38.2 now getting build error Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32586144/upgraded-to-swift-2-and-cocoapods-38-2-now-getting-build-error-command-bin-s)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I resolved the same issue, I removed "Build" folder once in my project.

Same issue: [upgraded to swift 2, and cocoapods -.38.2 now getting build error Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32586144/upgraded-to-swift-2-and-cocoapods-38-2-now-getting-build-error-command-bin-s)

But I can't use "Clean Build Folder", so I removed "Build" folder in my Mac Finder.

Answer (score 0):

I Had the same issue, My Project have integration of Unity also, In Project Settings, there is a UNITY_iOS_PATH that path was static in my case, I have made that path Dynamic to Unity Folder and it worked for me.